# Need help attaching a pdf file that I am saving into an email

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, save

Currently my code is below. It works well but for some reason it will not let me attach the file that I am saving. I have tried rewriting it several times but it won't work. Please let me know if there is an easy fix to this.

```
Sub Email_Sheet_Click()

Dim objOutlook As Object
  Dim objMail As Object
  Dim signature As String
  Dim oWB As Workbook
  Set oWB = ActiveWorkbook



 s = Range("F9").Value

'
 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
     s, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties _
     :=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True


PDF_File = "Q:\227_Saginaw\Texas\UFPIndustrial RFQ Quotes" & Format(Now, "YYMMDD") & ActiveSheet.Range("F6") & ".pdf"


Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With objMail
    .Display
End With
    signature = objMail.HTMLBody
With objMail
    .To = ActiveSheet.Range("F6")
    .Subject = ActiveSheet.Range("F11")
    .HTMLBody = "<font face=" & Chr(34) & "Calibri" & Chr(34) & " size=" & Chr(34) & 4 & Chr(34) & ">" & ActiveSheet.Range("F12") & "<br> <br>" & "Insert email body here" & "<br> <br>" & signature & "</font>"

End With

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: And you tried `.Attachments.Add`...?

Comment: Yes I have. Maybe I am adding the wrong thing after do you have any suggestions

Comment: Maybe you should `Debug.Print PDF_File` to see if it is what you think it is?

Comment: You used `s` when creating the PDF (?)

Comment: So everything is working but for some reason it will not attach the file even if i do .Attachments.Add s.file

Comment: Do you have `On Error Resume Next` hiding out somewhere? Also - `s` is a `Variant/String` so you can't do `s.File`.

Comment: No I do not. if you were to write the Attachments.Add. what do i need to put after that?

Comment: I will refer you to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) :-)

Comment: `objMail.Attachments.Add "fullPath\To\Your\File\Goes\Here.pdf"`